# Searching text on google in LibreOffice (from context menu or otherwise)?

Tags: firefox, libreoffice, search, google

Is it possible to search a text in google or other search engine in Firefox from context menu in LibreOffice?

Translating texts I need to go to the internet to look up the words and see context etc.

Could I do it directly from LibreOffice somehow?

Would look something like:

[image]

Comment: I don't know about Libreoffice menus, but you could search mouse selection anywhere by using an app like [Artha](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/artha/), or by keybinding `sh -c 'firefox "http://translate.google.com/#en/fr/$(xclip -o)"'` (example given translate english into french).

Comment: you mean that by Artha I could search google from LibreOffice? if that's the case please provide specific answer as such - instead of comment: i myself know nothing about keybinding, and therefore need a limited specific solution (instead of analogy)

Comment: No, these are alternatives as I don't know anything about Libreoffice. That's why it's a comment. You would have to use a shortcut (eg Ctrl+Alt+G) instead of going into Libreoffice's menu after selecting some text. Artha doesn't open Google in Firefox, it has its own popup window with results. The command I gave you will open google translate in Firefox with your mouse selection (text highlighted) as a query. Use `sh -c 'firefox "https://www.google.com/search?q=$(xclip -o)"'` if you want regular Google over Google translate. And obviously, that would work everywhere, not just LibreOffice.

Comment: @user55822: so, i have created a question so as to allow from you a full answer if you please: http://askubuntu.com/q/222240/47206

Comment: @user55822: my new question received an answer entirely based on your comment. all credit to you. i have edited the title of this one. if you wish to provide a full answer you may do it here or to the other one. but this is a duplicate now. Everything is pretty clear to me now. thank you

Comment: @user55822:but how would that be for bing translator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question received an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/222340/47206) when I created [a more general question](https://askubuntu.com/q/222240/47206) to clarify the comment given by [user55822](https://askubuntu.com/users/55822/user55822) to this question.

I will not delete this question, although now it is a duplicate of the other one, because here we have the comment that deserves all the credit for the solution.

So, I'll just flag it as duplicate so that the comment with the solution will stay visible.