# Select text and send it to google search and google translate from shortcut

Tags: internet, search, google

It seems possible (as I learned from a comment to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/216770/47206) made by [user55822](https://askubuntu.com/users/55822/user55822)) to use a command in order to search a term on the web by using "keybinding" the way Aretha is used.

What the aforementioned user says is that

"you could search mouse selection anywhere by using an app like Artha, or by keybinding `sh -c 'firefox "http://translate.google.com/#en/fr/$(xclip -o)"'` (example given translate english into french)"

A lot of things are obscure for me here. I could use Artha **or** keybinding (as alternative), or both? How to do that in each case?

and

"The command I gave you will open google translate in Firefox with your mouse selection (text highlighted) as a query. Use `sh -c 'firefox "https://www.google.com/search?q=$(xclip -o)"'` if you want regular Google over Google translate. And obviously, that would work everywhere"

I do not know what to do with that formula. What should I do exactly? How to use it? In what application?

Comment: the answer to this question is of course true not only for text editors, but **for selected text in any text page** including web browsers and so on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will try to explain it...
the command `sh -c 'firefox "https://www.google.com/search?q=$(xclip -o)"'` will open firefox in www.google.com searching the words you have selected with your mouse.
To use it , you should install **"xclip"**

1. Go to the terminal and type `sudo apt-get install xclip`
2. Then you can create a script with the command, create a "new document" and named as "search-google.sh"
3. Open the file with gedit and put these lines:
   [image]
4. Save the file in your home eg: /home/user/search-google.sh
5. Then change the permissions to make the script executable in the terminal type: `chmod 764 /home/user/search-google.sh`
6. Then you can create a custom keyboard shortcut to execute the script.
7. Go to **System Settings > Keyboard > shortcuts > Custom Shorcuts**
   [image]
8. Add a new item and fill the fields Name:`search-google` and Command:`sh/home/user/google-search.sh`
   [image]
9. Then give a keyboard shorcut to the script...click in **"Disabled"** and press the keys to the shortcut. eg: `Ctrl+Alt+G`
   [image]
10. So, if you are in a web page or any document and you select or (text highlighted) a word or phrase... then press the keys for the shortcut eg: `Ctrl+Alt+G` and Firefox will open searching in google for the text you have highlighted o selected.

On the other hand I think the [user55822](https://askubuntu.com/users/55822/user55822) tried to say was the Artha
application works like this command.. the difference is by default if you have a text selected with `Ctrl+Alt+W` Artha will serch for that text but **"offline"** (*As far as I know.)*
But you can use both, if you need to search in Artha select the text and press the
 shorcut keys `Ctrl+Alt+W`, but if you want to look in google **"online"** you can use the script with the shorcut `Ctrl+Alt+G.`

All the credit for the command is for [user55822](https://askubuntu.com/users/55822/user55822)

Hope will be useful.

**Edit**: The above instructions on setting the shortcut are for **Ubuntu (proper)**.
To set the shortcut for that script (or for any script like that) in **Xubuntu**, see the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/90513/47206). To set the shortcut in **Lubuntu** (which does not have a GUI for that purpose):

Paste in Terminal:

```
sudo gedit ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

There are a lot of groups of lines that set the keybinds and look like so:

```
<keybind key="C-A-t">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>x-terminal-emulator</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
```

To add a keybind for the google search script, insert this at the end of one of those groups:

```
<keybind key="C-A-g">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>sh ~/search-google.sh</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
```

Comment: @cipricus if you use `firefox -search "$(xclip -o)"`, firefox will use your default search engine to search for the selected text, if you set your search engine to bing then that should work. Apart from that, yes, you'd have to set different search engines separately.

Comment: @evilsoup: it seems that puting `sh -c 'firefox -search "$(xclip -o)"' `in the script searches the item in google no matter what i set as default search engine. but is it not possible to adapt `sh -c 'firefox "https://www.google.com/search?q=$(xclip -o)"'` to open text in bing translator and to invoke that by shortkey no matter the ff search settings?

Comment: @cipricus if you want to search in Bing, just change the line to

Comment: `sh -c 'firefox "www.bing.com/search?q=$(xclip -o)"'`, if you want to translate I would recommend **Google Translate**, just change the line to `'sh -c 'firefox "http://translate.google.com.ar/#en/es/$(xclip -o)"'` in this case from English (en) to Spanish (es). If you want to translate in Bing you can try with xdotool, `sudo apt-get install xdotool` and create the [script](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1443613/)

Comment: has something changed with google translate? cannot seem to make that work lately

Answer (score 3):

To have a short and clear answer based on the main one:

---

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

Add the following commands (worked directly for me, no script needed), for **Google search**:

```
sh -c 'firefox "https://www.google.com/search?q=$(xclip -o)"'
```

For **Google translate** (example for French to English):

```
sh -c 'firefox "http://translate.google.com/#fr/en/$(xclip -o)"'
```

replacing the language and browser if needed.

For **Google Translate** to English from any (auto-detected) language:

```
sh -c 'firefox "http://translate.google.com/#auto&tl/en/$(xclip -o)"'
```