# Can a script starting with a bad shebang line work?

Tags: scripts, xfce, shortcuts, lxde

Creating certain scripts to use in Lubuntu/LXDE as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/222340/47206) that should look like this

[image]

and were made to be run by shortcut as described in the last part of that answer, in order to search on the internet a selected text, I have made a mistake: I have started certain scripts with the line

```
#! bin/bash
```

instead of

```
#! /bin/bash
```

but only discovered the error after trying to use the same scripts in a different system (Xfce in Mint), which made me search and find [the answer here](https://superuser.com/a/548477/162573), which suggested the correction: and now the corrected scripts work as intended in Mint/Xfce.

**But the scripts with the bad line are still working in Lubuntu as if the bad line was not that bad!**

(The lxde shortcut settings are in `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` and they clearly indicate scripts that contain the bad line.)

How is this possible?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/238002/is-bin-sh-read-by-the-interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely that different shells/interpreters aren't overly strict, and either don't pay attention to the shebang, or don't fault when the interpreter in the shebang doesn't exist. I would imagine the second is more likely.

What shell were you using in case?

Comment: `What shell were you using`: I'm not sure: it works in Lubuntu 12.10, but not in Linux Mint 14 with Xfce 4.10

Comment: cduffin is correct. If you run the script with bash you will get an error `bad interpreter: bin/bash: no such file or directory` . If you run the script with sh or zsh it will work.