# Using shortkeys to search the internet for a term selected in a text editor/viewer running under Wine?

Tags: wine, internet, search, text, google

There is a very elegant [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/222340/47206) to use shortkeys to search the internet (or translate on Google Translation etc) a text selected in a text editor/viewer, but that solution does not seem to work in programs installed under Wine, like Notepad and Office 2007.

I wander what the cause might be and whether there is a way to make it work.

(I created this question to bring this into spotlight, but in the end it may be closed as duplicate of the other one, and its answers migrated there. So, in case you feel like closing this, please wait until an accepted answer is posted, or even better try to answer it - here or [there](https://askubuntu.com/q/222240/47206).)

---

Edit after  [IgnitE](https://askubuntu.com/users/58990/ignite)'s comments:

- A problem is that a text selected in a wine application it is not directly available outside wine. That might make unusable the script in the linked answer, which involves `xclip` (and that is clearly outside Wine).
- Wine is a Linux program.  I use libreoffice and office2007 for translating, writing and editing texts and want to be able to use shortcuts to search selected text in search engines or to translate it quickly in the same way. it saves me a lot of time and am already able to do it in libreoffice.
- Why not writing a wine script? winetricks is nothing but that

Comment: I don't think it's possible out of the box. Have a look at http://wiki.winehq.org/CopyAndPaste

Comment: I mean that, if you select any text in some wine application, it's not directly available outside wine. Also solution, you provided is making me search inside wine.

Comment: It's turning out to be more interesting than I thought!

Comment: @IgnitE: sorry for not noticing later: you said: `solution, you provided is making me search inside wine`. what is the solution you are reffering to? you mean the answer below on PDFXchange? in my case it opens my default Ubuntu browser, Firefox. It is an instance of a Wine text viewer from which selected text is searched outside Wine.

Comment: So my guess is, PDFXchange is copying the text to clipboard, which is *available* outside wine! I just said that the *selected* text is not available outside wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limited and incomplete answer, but maybe useful.

A program that runs under Wine and can search as required in the question is **PDF-Xchange Viewer**. The feature is part of this excellent program, only that it is not done by shortkey, but from the context menu.

So, selecting a text:

[image]

(the menu is already customized)

To add new options:

[image]

[image]

In this way the default Ubuntu web browser opens as expected.

(It is an example of text selected in a Wine program and searched outside Wine.)

Comment: the question asks for shortkeys, but i post this for reference, especially that i found the solution that works in the native text editors/viewers while asking for a context-menu search (http://askubuntu.com/q/216770/47206)